# Access service from Custom Validator in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation

I'm trying to access my service in order to make check for the validator but all i get is console full of errors I'm sure I'm just bad with syntax stuff =/

validator:

```
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';
import { AbstractControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';



export function titleValidator(control: AbstractControl,dataService:DataService) {

    console.log(dataService.moviesArray) -->> How can I access this service?
    if (control && (control.value !== null || control.value !== undefined)) {


        if (control.value=="test") {
            return {
                isError: true
            };
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

component:

```
this.movieForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', [Validators.required,titleValidator]],
      ...
    });
  }
```

If anyone has even another solution to make the custom validation in the component itself I would like any help.. thanks!

update: the errors:

```
AddMovieComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'moviesArray' of undefined
    at titleValidator (validator.ts:8)
    at forms.js:602
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeValidators (forms.js:602)
    at FormControl.validator (forms.js:567)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl._runValidator (forms.js:2510)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:2486)
    at new FormControl (forms.js:2794)
    at FormBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormBuilder.control (forms.js:5435)
    at FormBuilder.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormBuilder._createControl (forms.js:5473)
```

Comment: Show errors please. and make sure you've provided the service either in component you are using or in module.ts

Comment: @AliShahbaz added

Comment: It is clearly saying `moviesArray` is `undefined` because you haven't defined `moviesArray` in your service or initialized.

Comment: it only undefined when Im trying to use it inside this validator. all other places its initialized. Its like Im trying to get access there and i just cant. for example even if i initialize a string object in data service when i try to access it it says undefined

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to pass the service to the validator, there is no dependency injection here as this is not an Angular directive, it is a pure function. The way to do this is to use a factory method that accepts the service and creates a validator function.

```
export function titleValidator(dataService:DataService): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    console.log(dataService.moviesArray) // now you can :)

    // Test for control.value only, for eg:
    if (control.value && dataService.moviesArray.includes(control.value))
      return null;
    else
      return { 'movieNotFound' : { value: control.value } };
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
this.movieForm = this.fb.group({
  title: ['', [
         Validators.required,
         titleValidator(this.dataService)
  ]],
  ...
});
```

There is no need to check for the presence of control as Angular only calls the validator function with a valid control. Test only the value. More info [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators)

Comment: works great thank you. another thing is why I see that console.log 3 times and not 1?

Comment: Angular must be running the validation function 3 times at different stages of user input. I can't say exactly. Please upvote the answer if it worked for you :) I need 50 reputation before I can comment.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer with Angular 7/8 in 2019. I spent a lot of time with useless answers in related questions.